# React Native Touch events responding very slow

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was creating a very simple first Native app in React but my app is responding very slow to events such as touch

As suggested I have implemented several things like implementing `FlatList` instead of mapping and so on..

The two things which i think i might be doing wrong is updating state in

```
componentDidUpdate() {

var updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded];
 socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
  for (let i=0; i<updateCoinData.length; i++) {

    if (updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {

    //Search for changed Crypto Value
    updateCoinData[i]["perc"] = tradeMsg["message"]["msg"]["perc"]
    updateCoinData[i]['mktcap'] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']["mktcap"]
    updateCoinData[i]['price'] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']['price']

    //Update the crypto Value state in Redux
    this.props.updateCrypto(updateCoinData);

      }
    }
 })
```

or maybe calling `setState` too often in my child component.

If anyone wants reference this is the link to my repository 
https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto

These are the two files where most of the operations are happening

[Child Repository](https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/components/CoinCard.js)

[Parent Repository](https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/container/cryptoContainer.js)

I know it is probably too much to ask but can someone help me/suggest me how I can improve its performance.

Comment: you're updating redux inside loop !! it should be called once not updateCoinData.length times

Comment: @xadm it is being updated inside if condition of the loop. To elaborate, the socket message comes which have information about the specific cryto coin whose value is updated. I tried adding `break;` in my `if` condition but that didn't helped me.

Comment: and if condition is true     many times ?? message is for one id ??

Comment: @xadm only once but socket.io is sending message probably after every second. I am using https://github.com/CoinCapDev/CoinCap.io

Comment: componentDidUpdate is called many times, rename this method and call from componenDidMount

Comment: @xadm `componenDidMount` is called before render? Socket data needs to be updated once the data from  `http://coincap.io/front` hence I am calling it in `componentDidUpdate` 
And since socket is sending data every second hence I decided to got for `componentDidUpdate` (Not an expert here, so I might be missing something  here?)

Comment: then use a flag (like searchCoin) in local state to call it only once after receiving initial data

Comment: All of these suggestions are great, but also realize that when debugging js remotely, button presses are a bit laggy even when there's not a ton of code being called on the button press. (at least for me on a new macbook pro with 16GB ram). you might want to turn off debugging and see if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 'structural error', redux abusing. Not directly related to question (peformance) however it can have some indirect relation.

You're processing state/data locally while **it's a reducers responsibility**.

You should prepare payload from socket data and dispatch redux action/message. Reducer should create copy of prev state (use `slice()` to copy array, **spread operator '...' is slow**), search for matching id, update it and return as new state.

Main idea of reducer is extracting logic of state transitions to be simply testable. What can you test when only storing/receiving ready data set?

Comment: It would be a great help if you could share or add example for this
**You're processing state/data locally while it's a reducers responsibility**

Comment: any redux todo app .. ADD_TODO sends payload for only one record, reducer appends it to list (or updates record) - tons of tutorials about that